# Sort list of items in Django

Tags: django, sorting, post, django-models, django-views

I have a Django view called change_priority. I'm posting a request to this view with a commas separated list of values which is basically the order of the items in my model. The data looks like this:

```
1,4,11,31,2,4,7
```

I have a model called Items which has two values - id and priority. Upon getting this post request, how can I set the priority of the Item depending upon the list order. So my data in the db would look like.

```
1,1
4,2
11,3
31,4
2,5
4,6
7,7
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really give much detail about how exactly you're receiving the information, but here's a stab at it.

```
order = data.split(',') # convert data string to a list
objects = MyModel.objects.in_bulk(order)
for i, id in enumerate(order):
    obj = objects['id']
    obj.priority = i
    obj.save()
```